# R Shiny with MutationObserver

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, mutation-observers

I'd like to pass info that shiny has class `shiny-busy` to server side using `Shiny.onInputChange`. I almost did it using `MutationObserver`:

**isShinyBusy.js** in `www/` directory:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    var attributeValue = $(mutation.target).prop(mutation.attributeName);
    if (mutation.attributeName === "class" && attributeValue == "shiny-busy") {
      console.log("Class attribute changed to:", attributeValue);
      Shiny.onInputChange("isShinyBusy", true);
    } else {
      Shiny.onInputChange("isShinyBusy", false);
    }
  });
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
  observer.observe($("html")[0], {
    attributes: true
  });
});
```

**app.R**:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(src = "isShinyBusy.js")),
    br(),
    actionButton("btn", "Click")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$btn, ignoreInit = TRUE, {
      Sys.sleep(5)
      message("Button is pressed")
    })

    observe({
      is.shiny.busy <- input$isShinyBusy
      message("Shiny is busy: ", is.shiny.busy)
    })

  }
)
```

but that observer triggers many times as you can see in web browser console:

[image]

and in rstudio terminal:

[image]

Could you explain why this is happening?

Comment: That's because the observer triggers `shiny.busy`.